# asp.net Login control: what's wrong?

Tags: c#, asp.net, login-control

I'm working on ASP.NET app and in the master page C# code I want to access the login control, so I have the following code:

```
Login login = new Login();
login = this.Master.FindControl("login") as Login;
```

But, I get exception " Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when this line

```
login = this.Master.FindControl("login") as Login;
```

is executed.

I can't see what can be wrong...

Thanks.

Comment: On the same master page.

Comment: Is your Login control inside a LoginView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code mentioned above is in the master page, then try removing the Master portion of the code...

for example

```
login = this.FindControl("login") as Login;
```

The reason why this would work is because the current master page, is not embedded within another Master page. Therefore, you'll get an "object not set" error when trying to access the master's Master page (i.e. this.Master.FindControl())

Just wondering, if this is the case, is there a reason why you can't access the control by its name?

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my problem. And for your question - yes that was odd to me too, I couldn't access the control only by it's ID, so I searched for an answer in a book for .net and found out that the controls are accessible in this way in the master pages...

Answer (score 1):

If I read your question correctly, you have a master page and you are trying to use FindControl to find a control named login on **that** page.  If so, then you should be doing this:

```
login = this.FindControl("login") as Login;
```

because this:

```
login = this.Master.FindControl("login") as Login;
```

would be looking for the control in the master page that your current master page is nested in.

In other words, that last line of code would work if you had a nested master page - for Example Site.Master, and also had a nested child MasterPage named Section.Master  IF the login control was in the Site.Master and the code snippet were in the Section.Master.

(Hopefully that made sense.)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reference the login control directly by the ID element.

In markup:

```
<asp:Login runat="server" ID="MainLogin" ....... />
```

In code-behind:

```
MainLogin.Visible = false;
```

Comment: Would you not want to use Page.Master.FindControl??

Comment: Why would you want to?  Am I missing something here?

Comment: The controls can't be accessed only by their IDs in the Master page code behind class, so that's why I'm using the Page.FindControl("")

Comment: @Gog - Is your Login control inside a LoginView?

Comment: No, it is not... Look the answer of David Stratton above - everything is well described why I couldn't access the control and why the exception was thrown

Comment: That doesn't explain why you can't access it directly instead of using the FindControl method.